# Getting html elements in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This for loop does not run. This simple code is supposed to get all of the H5 elements on the page then get the "innerHTML" but the code never runs the for loop.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h5").length;
    alert(x);
    var y;
    var z;

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y = document.getElementsByTagName("h5")[i];
        z = y.innerHTML;
        alert(z + "  this");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should fire the method? myFunction();

Comment: I think, in for loop it should be (i = 0; i < x; i++)

Comment: `for(var i=0; i<x; i++) ....`

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for a `.length` property on `x` which is itself a length number. I think you mean:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h5");
```

Or of course

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
```

Depending on what you're doing with `x` afterwards

Comment: What was I thinking? Thanks, I guess I am getting way to OLD for this.  Thanks

Comment: Happens to the best of us. There is no age restriction on simple mistakes :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h5").length;
// ...
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
```

You're calling `.length` twice.

Comment: as the comment above states, way TOO OLD.  or I need more coffee thanks

Comment: Things like this happen everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but here's a little refactoring with some explanations.

```
function myFunction() {
    // Taking out the '.length' means you have a reference to all the h5s
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h5");
    alert(x);
    var y;
    var z;


   //Now since you're not including the .length above, this loop is correct
   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        //You since x is a reference to all the h5s now you don't
        //have to search for them again.
        y = x[i]; 
        z = y.innerHTML;
        alert(z + "  this");
    }
}
```

The important part there is just to use one `getElementsByTagName` call since that's a relatively expensive function. You definitely don't want to call it in a loop if you can avoid it. Generally to write good javascript you want to reuse references to DOM Elements as much as possible since the DOM is much slower than Javascript.